# How to reinstall default LDAP user store in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to add new attributes to the default LDAP user store in wso2 is.
But we don't have access to this store, the only way that we have is to reinstall user store with edited schemas.
Is there a way to reinstall the default LDAP server with new schemas?

Comment: Problem solved with migrating to JDBC userstore

Comment: WSO2 does not recommend using the embedded LDAP. Better to plug a different DB.